# Why is declaring `size_x` and `size_y` different from delcaring both in `size` in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, stacklayout

Why do these two blocks yield different results in kivy?

##### size

```
size: [50,50]
```

##### size_x and size_y

```
size_x: 50
size_y: 50
```

### Example

For example, the following code does not render the same looking app

##### size

Using just `size` has more padding around the label

[image: A "Hello World" app where "Hello" has more padding around it than the next image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

KV = """
StackLayout:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'

    Label:
        text: "Hello"
        size: [50,50]
        size_hint: None, None

    Label:
        text: "World"
        size: self.texture_size
        size_hint: None, None
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string( KV )
```

##### size_x and size_y

Using both `size_x` and `size_y` has less padding around the label

[image: A "Hello World" app where "Hello" has less padding around it than the previous image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

KV = """
StackLayout:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'

    Label:
        text: "Hello"
        size_x: 50
        size_y: 50
        size_hint: None, None

    Label:
        text: "World"
        size: self.texture_size
        size_hint: None, None
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string( KV )
```

My understanding is that `size` is merely a python list of `[size_x, size_y]`. Because of this, I'd expect that declaring them separately would yield the same results.

Why does declaring size as distinct `size_x` and `size_y` variables differ from declaring it just once with `size`?

Comment: `size_x`, `size_y` aren't default attr. They are generally termed as `width` and `height` respectively. Try setting these instead.

Answer (score 0):

`size_x` and `size_y` doesn't exist at all in the Kivy's API, and in the Kivy widget attributes.

[`size`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size) is a reference to a list of `[width, height]`. Theses code are identicals:

```
size: 100, 100
size_hint: None, None
```

is equal to:

```
width: 100
height: 100
size_hint: None, None
```

Your example have a different behavior because the default size of a unconstrained Widget is `100, 100`. So assigning `size_x` and `size_y` are meaningless.